# How to simulate not "safe thread" dictionary behavior?

Tags: c#, multithreading, testing, dictionary

I tried to reproduce not "save thread" dictionary behaviour
and implemented sample (see below).
I expected a dead-lock, but the tests worked without any problems.
Please, could you help and explain what a problem in my test and how to simulate multi-threaded dictionary error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace parallelTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            dictionary[2000] = "test";

            Parallel.For(0, 1000, i =>
            {
                string value;
                dictionary.TryGetValue(2000, out value);
                dictionary[2000] = String.Format("new value {0}", i);
                dictionary.Add(i, String.Format("{0}", i));
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("thread: {0}, {1}, {2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i, value));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by removing the Sleep(), but then it still won't do what you want. Unsafe -> race conditions -> undefined behavior. You can expect all sorts of errors but no deadlock.

Comment: I started my test without Sleep: no any errors

Comment: I have a "dead lock" issue in my production code (seems in Get from Dictionaty). Now I investigate the issue.

Comment: You can't have a deadlock unless you're locking. Besides, why don't you use a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)?

Comment: before to use ConcurrentDictionary I want to simulate my problem.

Comment: So, do you mean, I need to search lock in my code?

Comment: Well, it could either be a lock, or your thread could be stuck in a loop waiting for a condition to be met.

Comment: I removed Sleep() and Trace.WriteLine() and received exception System.ArgumentException

Comment: what does it mean _"**your thread could be stuck in a loop waiting for a condition to be met**"_?

Comment: by the way, next error found in my production code (thread was aborted by out timed out):
`Exception
 Message: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.get_Item(TKey key)` because the exception I started to investigate dead lock in Dictionary

Comment: Add the full exception to the question and post the relevant (surrounding) part of your sourcecode.

Comment: Btw: that error does not indicate a deadlock. Just 'undefined behaviour`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman stack trace of exception contains my code, which tries to get from dictionary value

Comment: @HenkHolterman I guess it was a deadlock, because all threads were aborted exactly in the same place

Comment: A deadlock is when (parts of) your program stop working. The Abort is not a standard reaction from a Dictionary, so there is something else in play here.

Comment: If you ant help you will need to post much more details from your actual code, maybe in a separate question. Or try to isolate the problem in a small demo program.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be facing a dead-lock because the `Dictionary` does not lock its internal data.
You might end up with unexpected data in the dictionary though. In this case: items that weren't added.

You'll need to check if the dictionary is as you expect it to be after the stress test.

```
for(Int32  index=0; index < 1000; index++)
{
    if(dictionary.Values.Any(index.ToString()) ==  false)
    {
          // problem
    }

}
```

By the way if you want to stress a dictionary you need to remove all other operation in the function e.g. String.Format. By doing that you will increase the chance to create a problem in the dictionary.

This is the internal method that is called when you call the public add method, and as you can see there is no lock in there.

```
private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }
    if (this.buckets == null)
    {
        this.Initialize(0);
    }
    int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 2147483647;
    int num2 = num % this.buckets.Length;
    int num3 = 0;
    for (int i = this.buckets[num2]; i >= 0; i = this.entries[i].next)
    {
        if (this.entries[i].hashCode == num && this.comparer.Equals( this.entries[i].key
                                                                   , key))
        {
            if (add)
            {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource
                                                      .Argument_AddingDuplicate);
            }
            this.entries[i].value = value;
            this.version++;
            return;
        }
        num3++;
    }
    int num4;
    if (this.freeCount > 0)
    {
        num4 = this.freeList;
        this.freeList = this.entries[num4].next;
        this.freeCount--;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.count == this.entries.Length)
        {
            this.Resize();
            num2 = num % this.buckets.Length;
        }
        num4 = this.count;
        this.count++;
    }
    this.entries[num4].hashCode = num;
    this.entries[num4].next = this.buckets[num2];
    this.entries[num4].key = key;
    this.entries[num4].value = value;
    this.buckets[num2] = num4;
    this.version++;
    if (num3 > 100 && HashHelpers.IsWellKnownEqualityComparer(this.comparer))
    {
        this.comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)HashHelpers
                                    .GetRandomizedEqualityComparer(this.comparer);
        this.Resize(this.entries.Length, true);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.